# Parsing CSS like file with Java

Tags: java, regex

I am working on something that involves a file structure similar to that of CSS but its a bit different
from CSS.
Here is the structure of the file

```
 <ELEMENT NAME>{
 Element attributes..1
 Element attributes..2
 Element attributes..3
 }
```

I have written a method to get Element Name

```
  public String getElementName(File jSfile){
    String elementName=null;
    StringBuffer sb = null;
    try{
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(jSfile));
    String line=null;
    while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
    Pattern element=Pattern.compile("\\<(.+?)\\>",Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher match=element.matcher(line);
    match.find();
    return match.group(1);
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    return e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }
    return elementName;

}
```

And use it like this..

```
 public static void main(String arg[]){
 CSSReader cs=new CSSReader();
 File f=new File("C:/Users/foo/bar/cascade.xyz");
 String z=cs.getElementName(f);
 System.out.print(z);
 }
```

But it always says `'No match found'`

> EDIT
>   I found that the file contains more than 1 sequence of  which had different name.
>   When I removed all other's and kept only one the code worked.

Sorry for being noob here.....DOES ANY ONE KNOW HOW I WOULD GO ABOUT MULTILINE....thanks a ton
Where am I going wrong

Answer (score 3):

You have 2 places where you write `br.readLine()`. The first is within the while condition and the second within the body. So the line that is read by the first one never gets used. I suspect this is the line that contains the token you are looking for.

Try changing this:

```
while(br.readLine()!=null){
    String line=br.readLine();
```

Into something like this:

```
String line = null;
while((line = br.readLine())!=null){
```

Comment: Did it, still no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare your String line before the while loop, and change your check for the while loop to assign, and then check for null:

```
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    // Do stuff with line
}
```

EDIT: Updated answer to reflect updated question

To account for multiple Elements, you could change your method to fill a list with each string that matches, rather than returning the first match. After the while loop completes, return that list.

Comment: that's what was suggested by @davidrac..
still no difference.

Comment: Have you tried iterating through debug and checking that the bufferedreader is actually producing data?

Comment: yes it reads the line and displays it,but I smell something wrong with regex.

Comment: ok, so you're trying to match "<ELEMENT NAME>". I'm not hugely familiar with regex, but "\\<(.+?)\\>" doesn't smell right to me either. I would think "<(.+?)>" would be the correct syntax? From the way it looks currently, it seems like your code is expecting something along the lines of "\<ELEMENT\>" to show.

Comment: I'm always a moment too late. Does your actual code read "while((null=br.readLine())!=null){", or iss that null a type?

Comment: OK, so now your issue is that you return after the first success. What you'll want to do more than likely is modify the while loop to add each new element to a list, and have your method return that list after the while loop completes, rather than just a single string.